# Country name from IP address

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, json

I want to get country name from IP address. I checked 8 different services but they are giving different results.

IP address:

```
217.156.194.220
```

Result:

Country: London

```
https://www.ip2location.com
https://freegeoip.app
https://ipinfodb.com
https://ipapi.co
```

Country: Spain

```
https://ip-api.com
https://ipwhois.io
https://ipgeolocation.io
https://ipstack.com
```

Which service is most accurate? I only need country name from IP address. I understand that city / GPS location can not be same, but I was expecting the country name to be same in all services.

Comment: *Which service is most accurate?* depends - which of the above is correct?

Comment: I don't know, I tried a random IP address and I got different countries.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout [GeoJS](https://app.geojs.io/), a highly available REST/JSON/JSONP IP Geolocation lookup API